# How do you style autofill inputs in Firefox?

Tags: css, firefox, autofill

`input:-webkit-autofill` can be used for Chrome/Safari, but `input:-moz-autofill` does not appear to do anything. Is there a way to customize the autofill styles in Firefox?

Comment: At first glance it seems like it's [not compatible with Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:-webkit-autofill)

Comment: Yeah, it's not supported as you found out (and Miro linked to). Here's some discussion: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=740979. In the thread, someone links to this: https://paul.kinlan.me/detecting-when-autofill-happens/ which has a workaround in detecting autofills allowing you to use JS.

Answer (score 8):

For Firefox you can do this:

```
input {
  filter: none;
}
```

Comment: This should be the Accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

You can style autofill in firefox but only with the webkit-prefix. (:-webkit-autofill)

To change the background color you need `filter:none` and the box-shadow trick which is also needed in chrome.

```css
:-webkit-autofill { /* also works for firefox! */
    filter:none; /* u need this for firefox */
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 100px #8f88 inset;
}
```